# change background color of specific button on click

Tags: jquery, css

The user clicks in order on button 1, 2, and lastly 3. After user clicks on button 3 a "congrats" box pops up, which is working fine.

When user clicks on button 1 the background of that button should turn grey, but button 2 and 3 should still be blue. Then when user clicks on button 2 it should turn grey just like button 1 is already grey and button 3 should still be blue. Then after user clicks on button 3 all buttons should be grey and the "congrats" box appears.

Right now they all stay blue until I click button 3. How to change that?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#button-1').click(function () {
    $('#button-2').click(function () {
        $('#button-3').click(function () {
            $('.button').css({background: 'grey'});
            $('#congrat-box').fadeIn(1200);
        });
    });
});
  
});
```

```css
.button {
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    background: blue;
    color: gold;
    border: 1px solid white;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px grey;
}
#congrat-box {
    background: orange;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 50px;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button-1" class="button">1</button>
<button id="button-2" class="button">2</button>
<button id="button-3" class="button">3</button>
<div id="congrat-box">Congrats!!!</div>
```

Provided snack snippet above, but here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Lsh3d35w/1/) if you prefer that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `$(this).css({ background: 'grey' });` after each button click to make it turn gray.  Maybe something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#button-1').click(function() {
    $(this).css({
      background: 'grey'
    });
    $('#button-2').click(function() {
      $(this).css({
        background: 'grey'
      });
      $('#button-3').click(function() {
        $(this).css({
          background: 'grey'
        });
        $('#congrat-box').fadeIn(1200);
      });
    });
  });

});
```

```css
.button {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  background: blue;
  color: gold;
  border: 1px solid white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px grey;
}
#congrat-box {
  background: orange;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button-1" class="button">1</button>
<button id="button-2" class="button">2</button>
<button id="button-3" class="button">3</button>
<div id="congrat-box">Congrats!!!</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use $(this)  and **if you won't** use css array  just use .css('background','gray');

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('#button-1').click(function () {
          $(this).css('background', 'grey');
          $('#button-2').click(function () {
            $(this).css('background', 'grey');
            $('#button-3').click(function () {
                $(this).css('background', 'grey');
                $('#congrat-box').fadeIn(1200);
            });
          });
      }); 
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the relevant part:

```
$('#button-1').click(function () {
    $('#button-2').click(function () {
        $('#button-3').click(function () {
            $('.button').css({background: 'grey'});
            $('#congrat-box').fadeIn(1200);
        });
    });
});
```

What's happening is that when `#button-1` is clicked, it adds an event listener for when `#button-2` is clicked, which adds an event listener for `#button-3`'s click, which finally makes all `.button`'s gray. You're not making each individual button gray as it is clicked.

Solution:

```
$('#button-1').click(function () {
    $(this).css({background: 'grey'});
    $('#button-2').click(function () {
        $(this).css({background: 'grey'});
        $('#button-3').click(function () {
           $(this).css({background: 'grey'});
            $('#congrat-box').fadeIn(1200);
        });
    });
});
```

On each click it will add the next button's listener as well as make *itself* gray. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lsh3d35w/2/).

Answer (score 1):

You can simply modify your code like this:

```
$('[id^="button"]').click(function () {
   $(this).css({background: 'grey'});
   if($(this).is('[id="button-3"]')){  
      $('#congrat-box').fadeIn(1200);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This line `$('.button').css({background: 'grey'});` is only executed when this function is hit: `$('#button-3').click(function () {` if you want each button in turn to turn grey apply the css class to the desired button on each click event, rather than only on the 3rd click event.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#button-1').click(function () {
    $('.button').css({background: 'grey'});
    $('#button-2').click(function () {
        $('.button').css({background: 'grey'});
        $('#button-3').click(function () {
            $('.button').css({background: 'grey'});
            $('#congrat-box').fadeIn(1200);
        });
    });
});

});
```